# Is there a more efficient compression algorithm to compress a 64base encoded string?

Tags: algorithm, encoding, lossless-compression

Say I have a 5 character string, and the characters can be one of 64 characters [a-zA-Z0-9+/]. I want to generate every possible string (64^5 strings) and store those strings in a DB and minimize the space I need to store them in my DB.

I don't know much about compression algorithms, but I was thinking that I could just encode each character into a 6 bit code with a base64 encoding and store each code contiguously in 4 byte blocks. I'd only be wasting 2 bits to store each string.

When I look up compression algorithms, I see stuff like huffman codings which supposed to be really efficient. For example, I took a look at [this post](https://www.programiz.com/dsa/huffman-coding#:%7E:text=Decoding%20is%20done%20using%20the,prefix%20of%20any%20other%20code.) about the huffman coding for the string "BCAADDDCCACACAC". The string is 15 characters long and each character is one byte to store, so the storage is 15 bytes. With a huffman coding, they reduce the size to 75 bits which is 10 bytes. But couldn't you do much better by just doing a base 2 encoding? There's only 4 characters, so you could store a contiguous stream of 15 2bit codes which would only require 30 bits = 4 bytes.

I'm just not sure if there's something I'm missing here.

Comment: Sure if your data contains only 4 possible characters then you can code each character with 2 bits, but that's not the common situation. As for storing 64^5 strings, that means 1,073,741,824 * 5 , about 5GB before compression. Unless you comress each entry separatepy, you would need to decompress a large chunk of data each time you access one entry.

Comment: *"There's only 4 characters"* — If that's all you have to support as *possible* values, then sure, you can compress it like that. But usually there are more possible values, so you'd need to include a header in your compressed stream that specifies the 4 possible bytes and what character they correspond to. Which may or may not be more efficient in the end.

Comment: There is a big difference between *needing to be able to decompress any given datum individually* and *needing the whole sequence, anyway*: The latter can exploit "self-similarity" as a general model, or better like *arithmetic progression* - the more the decompressor knows about the data, the better. If you *need to associate data* with each 5-place base-64 string, using 32 bit integers looks perfect (leave it to the DB ("automatic" primary key?)!). If not, refine your requirements description in the question, including why such (~5 bytes→4) compression seems useful.

Comment: The bulk of question does not align very well with its caption.

Comment: (The hyperlinked article on Huffman encoding is hand-wavy on encoding the coding table/tree (encoding the full histogram is a bit wasteful, and labelling the message length *bits* doesn't mean it's anything to do with the length of a minimal encoding of the coding table).)

Comment: @Noam Thanks. I would be compressing them all separately as 4 byte codes in a db which can be mapped to the string when I need it.

Comment: @deceze I see the distinction between the two cases, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @jacob then yes  I believe you can trivially compress each string of 5 characters to a sequence of 20 bits which requires 3 bytes.

Comment: @greybeard Basically each 6 character string will be a pre-generated URL, and I want to store these pre-generated strings as efficiently as possible. I'm pre-generating them so that when a user creates a page, I don't have to generate a unique page URL at runtime, I just request a new page URL from my API.

Comment: @Noam how could I store them in 3 bytes? 64^5 = 1073741824 possible strings. If I only use 3 bytes, how could I represent all those possible strings?

Comment: @jacob my bad, I had a miscalculation. 64 options require 5 bits, so the 5 characters would require 25 bits which indeed need a fourth byte for the last bit. For maximum efficiency you can compress groups of 8 strings.

Comment: @Noam 64 options requires 6 bits because 2^6 = 64. Each character would be represented by an encoding from 0b000000 to 0b111111

Comment: @jacob you are right. Next time I probably shouldn't try to make such calculations in head.